# Plug n' Play protocol for synced devices

Tags: control-system, light, protocol

I'm developing a highly customizeable lights system for emergency vehicles that consist on a series of devices, all of them in sync, with the posibility to program diferent sequences (of a moderate complexity) and with some type of plug n' play funcionality. So i need a way for syncing and configuring the individual patterns of the lights.

I was thinking in I2C, but i would have to implement some kind of dynamic adresses assignation. Also, i don't know how to sync a series of slave devices with out a master.

**In summary, i need to keep all the devices in sync, but working with their own sequence and with the posibility to reprogram each device's pattern independenly using an external device connected temporaly.**

So, any idea?

Comment: Use one extra pin in the cable arrangement to allow automatic configuration of one device as master.  Are you going for a line, ring, or star topology?

Comment: It all depends on your requirements.  There's dozens, if not hundreds of protocols out there, each with their own capabilities.  Some might even work despite them being intended for other uses.  JTAG might actually meet your needs.

Comment: I want to implement each node  using an attiny85, so I need something simple. Less cables is better, just 2 for power and 2 or 3 for communication and sync.

Answer (score 1):

How long is the cabling going to be?
Is there only one central controller?

I would go for CAN, but if you prefer simpler MCUs then RS-485 is a reliable option (just two wires + ground) as long as you can have a single control panel (otherwise you will have to design a protocol that will avoid collisions from two masters).

Comment: But how can I use either of those protocols to dynamically assign an address to a new device?. Also I don't want to have a master connected all the time, only for configuration purposes.

Comment: CAN and RS-485 is not exactly a protocol, bus physical layer standard. You have to design your own protocol (though CAN is truly a "non-master" system - every device is equal). If you connect the master only for configuration, then how the lights are controlled later? Only by connecting power?

Comment: The ligths would work independently, with their own configuration, but in sync with the others (not necessarily with the same blinking patterns)

Comment: If they don't communicate, just sync when powered on, then RS-485 is still a good option. Make a dip switch on each device "sync on". When you are programming the devices - turn that switch off and use any RS-485 protocol (eg. Modbus) to configure all your devices, then disconnect the programming adapter and turn the sync switch on (only one device) - only this one device will send, let's say, a single byte on the bus, other will listen and treat it as a sync signal.

Comment: Thanks filo, that will work. But how can I assign addresses to the new devices?.

Comment: I was thinking in connecting one by one, all with the same adress and with  the programmer connected, and telling the programmer to assign a new adress to the device with default adress. Then I can save the net-map in one of the devices for future reconfiguration. What do you think?

Comment: For example, I can program all the devices with a default adress, like 0x00. Then I connect one of them, tell the programmer to assign a new adress to 0x00 like 0x01. Then connect another device and tell the programmer, that will assign 0x02 to the new device. Finally, after I have connected all the nodes, the programmer would send a net-map to the first device for storage.

Comment: DIP switches, rotary switches or during programming (either in flash or in EEPROM depending on the MCU you are using).

Comment: I don't want to do it during programming cause i want all the devices to be identical until configuration (for production motives). Neither DIP or rotary switches, cause i can have up to 30 lights and that would be a mess. Because of that and modularity purposes i prefer to assign adresses during configuration stage. Do you think the method descrived above would work?

Comment: If you can afford to plug consecutive lights into the daisy chain during setup, then yes - by default every device can has a default address that will be changed by the master.